# Error parse JSON AJAX SAPUI5 consume web service spring

Tags: json, ajax, spring, web-services, sapui5

I have problem with AJAX call. error with parseerror. my code:

```
        $.ajax({  
               type: "GET",  
               url: "http://localhost:8089/SpringNew/tesget", 
               dataType: "jsonp",        
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function(resp){  
                 alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp );  
               },  
               error: function(request, errorText, errorCode){  
                 alert('Error121212: ' + errorText);  
               }  
             });
```

When I use this code, error with alert "Error121212: parseerror", and when I use dataType: "json", I have error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load".

[image: Error console]

I created web services with Java Spring, in webservices, I run in port 8089, and in frontend (I use SAPUI5) in port 8080.

my web services:

[image: Web Services]

How to fix this problem?

Thanks.
Bobby

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/
try to setup a callback-method `jsonp: 'callback'`

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to have missed some details. I believe this is because of the CORS headers from the server side. You should allow the origin that you are requesting with.

For allowing all, you can set the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to be `'*'`

This should solve your issue.

Comment: I already put that, but different error "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403". how to solve this problem?

Comment: jsonp is a workaround for CORS. I would prefer you use normal JSON and fix the CORS Problem instead of using JSONP.

Preflight is the OPTIONS Request, i think. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html

Comment: solved, I removed dataType and contentType. thanks for your support.!

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype contains an typo imho. It should be "json" instead of "jsonp". You may also try ...[url to service]/[entityset]?$format=json